# rails 5 - could could not generate rspec:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to build **restful  api using rails**

I am following the blog link tutorial to work out

https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one

but when i run this following command

`rails generate rspec:install`

It generates the following error

```
identical  .rspec
       exist  spec
      create  spec/C:/Users/Shad Munir/AppData/Local/Temp/d20170503-6768-l4n0e9/spec/spec_helper.rb
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253:in `mkdir': Invalid argument @ dir_s_mkdir - E:/todos-api/spec/C: (Errno::EINVAL)
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253:in `fu_mkdir'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:227:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:225:in `reverse_each'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:225:in `block in mkdir_p'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `mkdir_p'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:61:in `block in invoke!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:116:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:60:in `invoke!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions.rb:95:in `action'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:25:in `create_file'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:27:in `copy_file'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/directory.rb:94:in `block in execute!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/directory.rb:80:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/directory.rb:80:in `execute!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/directory.rb:66:in `invoke!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions.rb:95:in `action'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/actions/directory.rb:52:in `directory'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.5.2/lib/generators/rspec/install/install_generator.rb:23:in `block in copy_spec_files'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:89:in `mktmpdir'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.5.2/lib/generators/rspec/install/install_generator.rb:20:in `copy_spec_files'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/generators.rb:180:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require_command!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:145:in `generate_or_destroy'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:60:in `generate'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I tried some related solution from stack overflow but none of them is working .

Comment: Can you try to create the project on you C: drive instead?

Comment: Could you please add link to the SO questions that you tried but didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem a couple of days ago. What I had to do was delete all versions of RSpec from my machine and then run bundle install. This installed the latest version of RSpec and everything was good afterwards.